# When filtering a <ul> bullets disappear. How to make them stay?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a simple js for-loop to filter an unordered list as user types text into the input form. When results are displayed, however, every li's bullet disappears. How can I make them stay? I tried styling in the script (list-style-type) but either I'm doing it wrong, or it's not meant to work. Please help

```
        function searchHospital() {
var search, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
search = document.getElementById("searchKey");
filter = search.value.toUpperCase();
ul = document.getElementById("hospitals");
li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = "block";
        
        
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

}

https://jsfiddle.net/janeu/9xea2fvk/1/

Thank you!

Comment: try `li[i].style.display = 'unset'` or `'default'`.  A display of `block` is not the default display for `li` elements

Comment: You'll need to put another element inside of your `<li>` tag and apply your style to that element instead. And I'd advise using `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none`.

Comment: Another approach would be to use a `.hide { display: none; }` class that you toggle on/off the elements.  No clean up necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computed `display` for a list-item is `list-item`, not `block`.

So you need to set:

```
li[i].style.display = "list-item";
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6eb15drL/

Comment: That's it!Thanks so much